# Solve the equation $x^2-9\sqrt{x}+14=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, quartics

Solve the equation $$x^2-9\sqrt{x}+14=0$$

---

I think there are no real solutions. How to prove it?

Comment: Do you mean you think there is no real solution? Because $x=\varnothing$ is not the way to write that.

Comment: Let $u = \sqrt{x}$ and show $f(u) = u^4 - 9u + 14$ positive for $u \geqslant 0$.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: yes,i do

Comment: Actually here, you could graph $y=x^2+14$ and $y=9\sqrt{x}$ and observe they can't intersect, which shows there are no real solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Let's solve the equation
$$t^4-9t+14=0$$
The minimum value for the polynomial occurs when $t=\sqrt[3]{9/4}$ and it's
$$\sqrt[3]{2.25^4}-9\sqrt[3]{2.25}+14>\sqrt[3]{16}-9\sqrt[3]3+14>2.5-13+14>0$$

So it has no solution.

*Remarks*:

$$2.5^3=125/8<128/8=16$$
$$13^3=2197>2187=3^7=9^3\cdot 3$$

Comment: why you find the minimum value is $\sqrt[3]{9/4}$

Comment: Slightly easier to use that $\sqrt[3]{2.25}<\sqrt[2]{2.25}=\frac{3}{2}$ and then you get $>2.5-13.5+14$. Indeed, you only really need $\sqrt[3]{2.25^4}>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sqrt{x}=u$ then let
$$u^4-9u+14=f(u)$$

From which one must show that $f(u)$ is positive for $u \geq 0 $